# delete everything but one directory

Tags: bash, command-line-interface

I've got a `/tmp/test` directory. In it I've got a mixture of files and directories. One of those directories is `/tmp/test/to_be_kept`. Now I'd like to know how do I delete all the files and directories apart from `/tmp/test/to_be_kept` and everything what's in it? Thanks

Answer (score 7):

```
shopt -s extglob
rm -r /tmp/test/!(to_be_kept)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will produce some error messages which you can ignore when it tries to re-access directories that have already been removed:

```
find /tmp/test -mindepth 1 -type d -name to_be_kept -prune -o -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Here is a simple way:

  ```
  ls /tmp/test | grep -v to_be_kept | xargs rm -r
  ```
- If you want to delete hidden also:

  ```
  ls -a /tmp/test | grep -v to_be_kept | xargs rm -r
  ```

**Always test the output first!**

Try these first without the `| xargs rm -r` part! If you get the list of files and directories you wanted to delete you may as well apply...

Comment: +1 for workable solution complete with "safety first" instructions.